# Starting a new Activity from a ListView click

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, onitemclick

I have been trying to figure out how to create a code that allows the *user* to *input data* that is later stored in an **SQLite Database**. Then some of that *data* is displayed in a **ListView**. Next, when someone clicks on a *List Item*, it takes the user to a new **Activity** that displays the rest of the *data* that corresponds with what was displayed in the **ListView Item** that the *user* clicked on. I have the **Database** set up and the **ListView** is populated with the *data* I want there, now I need to figure out how to have the correct data *displayed* in the **Activity** that is started when the *user* *clicks* on a **List Item**. Does anyone know how I can find the *data* that is stored with the **Row Id** of the **Item** that was clicked on? All help is greatly appreciated! Also, please comment with any questions or if I need to explain my question better.

Here is some of my code...

Database Operations class -

```
      public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version = 1;

public static final String ACC_NAME = "acc_name" ;
public static final String ACC_PASS = "acc_pass" ;
public static final String ACC_NOTES = "acc_notes" ;
// public static final String ACC_TYPE = "acc_type" ;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "acc_info" ;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_info" ;
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

   // Creating the Table
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE table_info ( " +
               "_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
               "acc_name TEXT, "+
               "acc_pass TEXT, "+
               "acc_notes TEXT )";

public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DBinfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

     // Inserting the Information from edittexts in another activity

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String acc_name, String acc_pass, String acc_notes)

{
SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_NAME, acc_name);
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_PASS, acc_pass);
cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_NOTES, acc_notes);
// cv.put(DBinfo.ACC_TYPE, type);
long k = SQ.insert(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
Log.d("Database operations", "One raw inserted");

}
     // This populates the ListView

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop)
{

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] coloumns = {KEY_ROWID,DBinfo.ACC_NAME,DBinfo.ACC_PASS,DBinfo.ACC_NOTES};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}

   // This is really where I need help.. This code doesn't have errors, however it crashes upon 
   //  clicking a ListView Item. This is also my attempt at a working code, it might not really 
   //   make any sense and I am sorry about that. Again, I am trying to receive the info that 
   //    corresponds with the row of info that was selected in the ListView.

public Cursor getName(DatabaseOperations dop) {

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] name102 = {KEY_ROWID,DBinfo.ACC_NAME};
    Cursor c = SQ.query(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, name102, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
public Cursor getPass(DatabaseOperations dop) {

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] pass102 = {KEY_ROWID,DBinfo.ACC_PASS};
    Cursor b = SQ.query(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, pass102, null, null, null, null, null);
    return b;
}
public Cursor getNotes(DatabaseOperations dop) {

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] notes102 = {KEY_ROWID,DBinfo.ACC_NOTES};
    Cursor a = SQ.query(DBinfo.TABLE_NAME, notes102, null, null, null, null, null);
    return a;
}


public String getNameRow(int prePosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor c = this.getName(this);
    String NAME = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
    return NAME;
}

public String getPassRow(int prePosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor b = this.getPass(this);
    String PASS = b.getString(b.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
    return PASS;
}

public String getNotesRow(int prePosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor a = this.getNotes(this);
    String NOTES = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
    return NOTES;
}

}
```

This is the activity that I am trying to get the specific data to

PassView -

```
public class PassView extends Activity {

Main_Screen mainScreen;
DBHelper myDb;
DatabaseOperations myDb1;
TextView nameView1;
TextView passView;
TextView notesView;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_passview);

        myDb1 = new DatabaseOperations(this);
        mainScreen = new Main_Screen();
        nameView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameView1);
        passView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passView);
        notesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notesView);
        int prePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 1);

    openDB();
        String name0 = myDb1.getNameRow(prePosition);
        String pass0 = myDb1.getPassRow(prePosition);
        String notes0 = myDb1.getNotesRow(prePosition);
    closeDB();
        nameView1.setText(name0);
        passView.setText(pass0);




notesView.setText(notes0);


} 

private void closeDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myDb = new DBHelper();
        myDb.close();
}

private void openDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myDb = new DBHelper();
        myDb.open();
}

public int prePosition() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int prePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 1);
    return prePosition;
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call getItemAtPosition() on your list view, with the position you want.

Comment: Would the position I want just be the ID number?

Comment: Depends on the data structure you use..like if you have data as list..you can use listview position to fetch from list

Comment: It took a little bit of playing around with the code, but I got it! Thanks for the help!